# How to split npy 1D array accroding to dtypes.names?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a npy file with shape [13044,] with the trajectory data where 'coords' gives coordinates of trajectory data . It has 16 dtypes with following

```
dtype([('frame_num', '<i4'), ('mean_x', '<f4'), ('mean_y', '<f4'), ('var_x', '<f4'), ('var_y', '<f4'), ('length', '<f4'), ('scale', '<f4'), ('x_pos', '<f4'), ('y_pos', '<f4'), ('t_pos', '<f4'), ('coords', '<f4', (16, 2)), ('trajectory', '<f4', (15, 2)), ('hog', '<f4', (96,)), ('hof', '<f4', (108,)), ('mbh_x', '<f4', (96,)), ('mbh_y', '<f4', (96,))])

tracks[0]
```

gives

```
  (15, 186.33582, 92.24783, 2.6624618, 0.22911347, 9.241288, 1., 0.51759946, 0.38436598, 0.04166667, [[182.      ,  92.      ], [182.5449  ,  92.09226 ], [183.10237 ,  91.61799 ], [183.64798 ,  92.135086], [184.26779 ,  92.16737 ], [185.04352 ,  92.200066], [185.68985 ,  92.19117 ], [185.94293 ,  92.222855], [186.41994 ,  92.30446 ], [187.35497 ,  92.39461 ], [187.94893 ,  92.39315 ], [188.32193 ,  92.47165 ], [189.05319 ,  92.40751 ], [189.58992 ,  92.37913 ], [189.8503  ,  92.6842  ], [190.59416 ,  92.30396 ]], [[ 0.05896436,  0.0099837 ],...
```

The first element is last frame_number, from 10 th elements it gives 16 coordinates of trajectory from beginning 2nd coordinate of 1st frame and last is of 15th frame

```
[182.5449  ,  92.09226 ], 1st frame feature point
   [183.10237 ,  91.61799 ],trajectory of that feature point at second frame.. 
[183.64798 ,  92.135086], [184.26779 ,  92.16737 ], [185.04352 ,  92.200066], [185.68985 ,  92.19117 ], [185.94293 ,  92.222855], [186.41994 ,  92.30446 ], [187.35497 ,  92.39461 ], [187.94893 ,  92.39315 ], [188.32193 ,  92.47165 ], [189.05319 ,  92.40751 ], [189.58992 ,  92.37913 ], [189.8503  ,  92.6842  ], [190.59416 ,  92.30396] trajectory of feature point at last frame

tracks[500]



(19, 101.504395, 133.30353, 4.431484, 0.41493973, 14.826186, 1.9999999, 0.28195664, 0.55543137, 0.06388889, [[ 93.99999 , 133.99998 ], [ 95.10257 , 133.91016 ], [ 96.17397 , 133.8509  ], [ 97.26843 , 133.84372 ], [ 98.360085, 133.75041 ], [ 99.31606 , 133.46017 ], [100.22412 , 133.29907 ], [101.10831 , 133.0922  ], [102.029564, 132.93976 ], [102.92373 , 132.95956 ], [103.90272 , 132.80684 ], [104.84618 , 132.84692 ], [105.69725 , 132.90834 ], [106.740944, 133.00175 ], [107.67655 , 133.08873 ], [108.69984 , 133.09813 ]], [[ 0.07436688,....
```

First element - last frame is 19
from 10 th elements it gives 16 coordinates of trajectory

```
[95.10257 , 133.91016 ],5th frame of a feature point
 [ 96.17397 , 133.8509  ], [ 97.26843 , 133.84372 ], [ 98.360085, 133.75041 ], [ 99.31606 , 133.46017 ], [100.22412 , 133.29907 ], [101.10831 , 133.0922  ], [102.029564, 132.93976 ], [102.92373 , 132.95956 ], [103.90272 , 132.80684 ], [104.84618 , 132.84692 ], [105.69725 , 132.90834 ], [106.740944, 133.00175 ], [107.67655 , 133.08873 ], -18 th frmae
[108.69984 , 133.09813 ]-19 th frame of that trajectory point
```

I need to save npy now as : 
Frame number coordinates,........,last frame number coordinates

example

```
[5, 95.10257 , 133.91016 ][ 6, 96.17397 , 133.8509  ], [7,  97.26843 , 133.84372 ], [ 8, 98.360085, 133.75041 ], [9,  99.31606 , 133.46017 ], [10, 100.22412 , 133.29907 ], [11, 101.10831 , 133.0922  ], [12, 102.029564, 132.93976 ], [13, 102.92373 , 132.95956 ], [14, 103.90272 , 132.80684 ], [15, 104.84618 , 132.84692 ], [16, 105.69725 , 132.90834 ], [17, 106.740944, 133.00175 ], [18, 107.67655 , 133.08873 ], 
    [19,108.69984 , 133.09813 ]
```

In this way i want to save in npy file. Just i want to make new npy file with frame _num, coordinates and removes other data

---

**EDITED**

```
f=np.zeros((len(tracks),15,3),float)
n_tracks,n_pts,_=tracks['coords'].shape
for i in range(len(tracks)):
    get_frame_num=tracks['frame_num'][i]
    for j in range((get_frame_num-14),get_frame_num+1):
        print(j)
        f[:,:,0]=float(j)
        f[:,:,1:]=tracks['coords'][:n_tracks,:n_pts-1]
```

**In array[0], first columns are 0, 0, 0 . After this result i want to change to 1,2,3 In array [1], first column are 1,1,1. After this result , I want to change 2,3,4 to for trajectory coordinates, Using nested for loop makes ipython crash**

Comment: provide sample data.

Comment: Added sample data 
tracks[0]

Comment: Reference each field by  name, `arr['x']`

Comment: `data.tracks['frame_rate']` etc.

Comment: Main problem is that I need to extract tracks['coords'] and find start point and end point to find speed . But i couldn't figure out how to use track['coords'] first data and end data.

Comment: 'coords' is a (16,2) dtype, so `tracks['coords']` will be 3d `(13044, 16,2)`.  `[0]` would select the first (16,2) array, `[-1]` the last.

Comment: The initial dtype display should be a text copy-n-paste, not an image. Initially I had trouble reading it. And despite the request, the data.tracks[0] paste doesn't help; the dtype is too complex and large.

Comment: hpaulj ..I have edited question and wrote what actually I want to do

Comment: I'm having problems following the coordinates layout; maybe it's just too complicated to grasp with a casual read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188167/discussion-between-himal-acharya-and-hpaulj).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616526/how-to-save-subarray-in-npy-file
I have added another question clarifying my main problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to illustrate how an array like yours can be used.

First I have to make an array with a compound dtype.  A simplification of yours:

```
In [729]: dt = np.dtype([('frame','i'), ('coord', 'f', (3,2))])
In [730]: arr = np.zeros((5,), dtype=dt)
In [731]: arr['frame'] = np.arange(5)
In [732]: arr['coord'].shape
Out[732]: (5, 3, 2)
In [733]: arr['coord'] = np.arange(30).reshape(5,3,2)
In [734]: arr
Out[734]: 
array([(0, [[ 0.,  1.], [ 2.,  3.], [ 4.,  5.]]),
       (1, [[ 6.,  7.], [ 8.,  9.], [10., 11.]]),
       (2, [[12., 13.], [14., 15.], [16., 17.]]),
       (3, [[18., 19.], [20., 21.], [22., 23.]]),
       (4, [[24., 25.], [26., 27.], [28., 29.]])],
      dtype=[('frame', '<i4'), ('coord', '<f4', (3, 2))])
```

`arr['frame']` and `arr['coord']` would be like the fields you could extract from your array.

I'm not quite sure you want to join the frame number and coords, but here's a guess.  First make blank array to hold the joined data.

```
In [735]: x = np.zeros((5,3,3),float)
```

And copy values from `arr`:

```
In [736]: x[:,:,0] = arr['frame']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-736-7270535f17a6> in <module>()
----> 1 x[:,:,0] = arr['frame']

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5) into shape (5,3)
```

Oops.  `x[:,:,0]` is a (5,3) array, while `frame` is (5,); I need to change the (5,) to (5,1) so it can be broadcasted to (5,3):

```
In [737]: x[:,:,0] = arr['frame'][:,None]
In [738]: x[:,:,1:] = arr['coord']         # (5,3,2) both sides
In [739]: x
Out[739]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 0.,  4.,  5.]],

       [[ 1.,  6.,  7.],
        [ 1.,  8.,  9.],
        [ 1., 10., 11.]],

       [[ 2., 12., 13.],
        [ 2., 14., 15.],
        [ 2., 16., 17.]],

       [[ 3., 18., 19.],
        [ 3., 20., 21.],
        [ 3., 22., 23.]],

       [[ 4., 24., 25.],
        [ 4., 26., 27.],
        [ 4., 28., 29.]]])
```

`np.save(filename, x)` should work fine.  `np.save` works with any numpy array, even this 3d one.  No need to iteration as you attempt in the other question.  `np.save` can handle `arr` too.

I could also construct `x` by concatenation. But first I have to replicate the `frame` to a compatible shape.  Remember `coord` is (5,3,2):

```
In [744]: f = np.repeat(arr['frame'][:,None],3,axis=1)
In [745]: f.shape
Out[745]: (5, 3)
In [746]: y = np.concatenate((f[:,:,None], arr['coord']), axis=2)
In [747]: y.shape
Out[747]: (5, 3, 3)
In [748]: np.allclose(x,y)
Out[748]: True
```

`

Comment: In array[0], first columns are 0, 0, 0 . After this result i want to change 1,2,3 
In array [1], first column are 1,1,. After this result , I want to change 2,3,4 to for trajectory coordinates, Using nested for loop makes ipython crash